# Set path for a specific command under OSX

Tags: linux, macos, shell

I have *libtool* command in both path :

```
/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/libtool
```

and

```
/usr/bin/libtool
```

The current command is recognized under macport which is the first path. 
What can I do if I want the command *libtool* run from */usr/bin/libtool* without removing the macport path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PATH` doesn't make sense in the context of individual commands.  It is a list of directories in priority order.  If you want one directory to take precedence over another, put it earlier in the path.

However, there is a way to influence resolution order indirectly; create a directory with a high precedence (i.e. put it early in your `PATH`) and populate it with symlinks to the preferred versions of programs which would otherwise resolve incorrectly.

A natural choice would be `/usr/local/bin` but on OSX in particular, it has (bewilderingly IMHO) a lower precedence than `/usr/bin` out of the box.  Maybe simply fix that in your own `.bash_profile` by putting it first.  Or create a dedicated directory for this specific purpose and put that first in your path.

Of course, in your personal Bash (or other shell's) profile, you can also simply create a function or alias which causes the `PATH` to be bypassed entirely.  This generally only makes sense for interactive use, though.

Comment: Thanks, solved by simply create a symbolic link in **/usr/local/bin**, and move the path in lower precedent in **.bash_profile**.